# iPhone: How To call method on NSSlider touch end?

Tags: iphone, ios4, uislider

I Have UISlider in my iphone application and i want to call method (function ) when the user sliding ends ... what is the simplest way to do that?

Comment: iOS doesn't have an `NSSlider`. Did you mean `UISlider`?

Comment: yes sorry that's what  i ment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

connect a callback to onTouchUpInside (and optionally onTouchUpOutside as well)